# Post variable while posting form

Tags: php

I have form that posts data to `h1.php`

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="h1.php" method="post" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>
//$jobType="sale";
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In h1.php side I collect data:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    Item name is: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Item price is: <?php echo $_POST["price"]; ?><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This works fine, but now I need to post `jobType` text variable that has no input control and in `h1.php` side I will take it like:

```
<html>
    <body>
    Item name is: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Item price is: <?php echo $_POST["price"]; ?><br>
    Job type: <?php echo $_POST["jobType"]; ?><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to transfer variable using post form

Comment: what's this `//$jobType="sale";` doing in your first code?

Comment: To access that way in php, create `hidden` input field with `jobType` name

Comment: either via $_GET (in url) or as hidden input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="h1.php" method="post" >
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>

<input type="hidden" value="sale" name="jobType">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

see also http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html

Comment: I think sessions would be better. That way users can't mess with the value.

Answer (score 2):

if $jobtype is a variable use `type="hidden"` like the following code:

```
<form action="h1.php" method="post" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print $jobtype; ?>" name="job_type">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```